# Problem With Alignment of Image on TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I'm using a c# winform `TabControl`. I've created an `ImageList`, associated it with the `TabControl` and populated it with a few images. The problem is, when I set the `ImageIndex` or `ImageKey` for a particular tab the image shows up on the tab, but it covers the text that is on the tab. To add to my confusion, one `TabPage` in particular renders the image in the correct location (image followed by text). The page that has the image in the correct location is whatever `TabPage` I set the `ImageIndex` property on first...

I've googled around and found a post on another forum where someone described this problem and everyone said they couldn't recreate the problem. Any ideas what the problem could be? I really don't know what to try.

**Edit**

Sorry for the confusion. I have a `TabControl` object with it's `ImageList` property associated with an `ImageList` that has two images. When I set the `ImageIndex` property on a `TabPage` in the `TabControl` (from what I read) it is supposed to render the actual tab on the `TabControl` as image followed by text. This is what happens when I set the image for the **first** `TabPage` in my `TabControl` but every tab following that will be rendered with the image covering the text that is on the tab. So the text appears behind the image. I use a for loop to set the image for each `Tab`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabControl.TabPages.Count; i++) {
    tabControl.TabPages[i].ImageIndex = SOME_IMG_INDEX;
}
```

The `TabPage` at index 0 of the `TabControl.TabPages` collection will look normal (image followed by text). The others will have the image over top of the text. Even if I were to start the for loop iteration at index 2, index 2 would render correctly but any after that would have the image over the text. I hope this helped make the question clearer.

Comment: please attach here a picture so we can understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I've found to recreate your issue was when I changed the `SizeMode` property on the `TabControl`.

When I changed it to `Fixed`, the images and text were commingled.  Changing it back to `Normal' rendered everything correctly again.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415953/visual-c-sizemode-fixed-tab-text-alignment/6416636#6416636) talks about removing the tabs and adding them back in as a hack that works around this issue, posted at MSDN.  I tried the hack and it worked.

**Update:**

As Steve_Overflow pointed out, this is a simple work-around to update the tabs correctly:

```
tabControl1.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;

for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabPages.Count; i++)
  tabControl1.TabPages[i].ImageIndex = SOME_IMG_INDEX;

tabControl1.ItemSize = tabControl1.ItemSize;
```

Comment: That is exactly what the issue is. Thanks for posting. Unfortunately I need the SizeMode to be fixed. I'd really rather not use that work around, but it's better than nothing. I'm currently using `tabControl.ItemSize = tabControl.ItemSize` to trigger the event and its working fine. Does anyone else know of some less hackey way to solve this?

Comment: @@LarsTech very true. Like I said, that line is in there now and it will stay there unless someone offers up a better solution. Thanks for your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Fixed-Size Tabs , use theses codes together (Don't know why, but this will solve the problem)

```
tabControl.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Normal;
tabControl.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
```