# tabControlPages remove picture

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, imagelist

Try to find solution for next - on `mouseEnter` - show picture on `TabControl` page and  on `MouseLeave` - clear it.
Currently done - just show pic on tab.

There are a lot of question refered to "How to show" picture - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7248707/2012219) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3663603/2012219) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13953792/2012219) ant also a lot of others.
For this I use next way - add `imageList` and just show pic on `mouseEnter` -

```
private void tabControlPages_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabPageAdd.ImageIndex = 0;
    }
```

For removing - try to read about some methods on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.aspx) - but have found nothing (maybe not found).
As variant think, can put in collection transparent icon and just change it on `mouseLeave`, but think it's not a perfect solution. If use `imageListIcons.Images.Clear();` - it's fully clear `ImageList` - as and expected.

So, are ther is some solution avaliable for correct way to hide/show icon on tab from  `tabControl` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `ImageIndex = -1` to remove the tab icon:

```
private void tabControlPages_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabPageAdd.ImageIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: all genius - so easy... thanks a lot - works perfect