# How to avoid image overlapping the text of TabPage in WinForms after setting it programatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, tabs, tabcontrol

I have a Windows Forms application with a `TabControl` that has two `TabPage` objects:

[image: Tab pages in their default state]

What I am aming for is a way to display an icon beside the titles of the tabs. For that, an `ImageList` is assigned to the `TabControl` so the `ImageIndex` property of the tab pages can be set. When I do that in the designer, it looks fine, but when changing it programatically in my code like this:

```
myTabControl.TabPages[0].ImageIndex = 0
```

, it has this weird overlapping effect:

[image: Tab pages when edited programatically]

How can I avoid this? Things I've tried are `myTabControl.PerformLayout()` and `myTabControl.Invalidate()`, but none of them worked. Thanks!

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7273650/14171304) workaround when you have the `SizeMode` property set to `TabSizeMode.Fixed`. The `ItemSize` property setter calls internal methods to recalculate the bounds and the parts (image and text) will be rendered correctly afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, there is a workaround solution:

```
myTabControl.ItemSize = myTabControl.ItemSize;
```

This only works if the `SizeMode` of the tab control is set to `TabSizeMode.fixed`. Thanks to Dr.Null (comment above) to point this out.

While this is simple though, it's not so elegant and confuses readers. I wonder whether there are other, intended solutions or whether this is a "hole" in WinForms Microsoft didn't consider.